# Google Maps Marker Array Objects Not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For a Google Maps project, I tried to store marker objects into an array, then placing them on the maps via a for loop. However, the markers does not seem to show themselves on the map. Code as listed below.

```
<script>
  function initialize(){

      var loc1 = {lat:24.256, lng:23.3536};
      var loc2 = {lat:63.456, lng:135.234};
      var loc3 = {lat:42.234, lng:153.234};
      var loc4 = {lat:38.737, lng:-150.181};
      var loc5 = {lat:4.816, lng:160.897};
      var loc6 = {lat:74.872, lng:-85.669};

      var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.025922,121.543449),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };
      var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

      //code
      markerArray = [];
      //code
      addMarker(loc1, 'marker1');
      addMarker(loc2, 'marker2');
      addMarker(loc3, 'marker3');
      addMarker(loc4, 'marker4');
      addMarker(loc5, 'marker5');
      addMarker(loc6, 'marker6');

      showMarkers();
  }

  function addMarker(location, name){

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      title: name,
      icon:ship_icon
    });

    markerArray.push(marker);
  } 
   function showMarkers() {
           if (markerArray) {
              for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
                 markerArray[i].setMap(map);
              };
           }
           else{
                alert("Carrier vessels marker cannot be loaded properly.");
           }
        }
</script>
```

The Google Map loads, however the markers do not. Could anyone figure out why this is the case? Thanks.

Comment: What is `ship_icon`?

Answer (score 1):

Your map variable does not exist in the addMarker() function, it is defined in the initialize() function as local.

Define it outside those functions and it will work :D

Comment: I tried to place addMarker() and showMarkers() inside initialize(), however it doesn't seem to help much...

Comment: @user3600725 that wasn't what overburn suggested.  Add `var map;` outside of your `initialize` function, so it becomes a global variable.  Then remove the `var` keyword before where you set `map` in the `initialize` function, so you're updating that global variable, not one local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. make your `map` variable global

or

2. pass it into the functions that need it

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/t1cmsd9k/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {

  var loc1 = {
    lat: 24.256,
    lng: 23.3536
  };
  var loc2 = {
    lat: 63.456,
    lng: 135.234
  };
  var loc3 = {
    lat: 42.234,
    lng: 153.234
  };
  var loc4 = {
    lat: 38.737,
    lng: -150.181
  };
  var loc5 = {
    lat: 4.816,
    lng: 160.897
  };
  var loc6 = {
    lat: 74.872,
    lng: -85.669
  };

  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.025922, 121.543449),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  //code
  markerArray = [];
  //code
  addMarker(loc1, 'marker1', map);
  addMarker(loc2, 'marker2', map);
  addMarker(loc3, 'marker3', map);
  addMarker(loc4, 'marker4', map);
  addMarker(loc5, 'marker5', map);
  addMarker(loc6, 'marker6', map);

  showMarkers(map);
}

function addMarker(location, name, map) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    title: name
  });

  markerArray.push(marker);
}

function showMarkers(map) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  if (markerArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(markerArray[i].getPosition())
      markerArray[i].setMap(map);
    };
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  } else {
    alert("Carrier vessels marker cannot be loaded properly.");
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```